# Graph part of sphere inside of a cone using MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have the following task:

"Graph the portion of the sphere `x^2+y^2+z^2=4`, that lies inside the cone `z=sqrt(x^2+y^2)`. Set axis: `-2<=x<=2, -2<=y<=2, -2<=z<=2`." using MatLab

I've tried searching MatLab help and Internet for some guidance, but cant seem to find the good answer to my problem. Can anyone solve this or advise on what method to use?

Comment: Please explain/add exactly what your problem is and what you have tried, we only can help you with the things you dont understand but we wont solve your homework.

Comment: use this https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/313786-plotting-a-spherical-segment

Comment: Hi, thank you for the link. I also found the most useful when trying to find a way to solve the problem. The only thing is that in this example the dome is getting cut off on point count (11 out 21). I've calculated that sphere and the cone will intersect at z=sqrt(2). So I've tried to input this in the code, but got an error:

Comment: show the code please